# Turn off card dimming in VerticalGridFragment in leanback sample

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

I am using the VerticalGridFragment from the git sample to just display information and do not want user interaction. I successfully turned off the user focusing in the CardPresenter.cs but I would also like to change all the cards so they are not dim.

Here is a screenshot of the class and the dimming I would like to turn off. http://corochann.com/verticalgridfragment-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-19-718.html

I have tried changing the alpha inside of the CardPresenter class but this does not seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated!

CardPresenter.cs

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    mDefaultBackgroundColor =
        ContextCompat.getColor(parent.getContext(), R.color.default_background);
    mSelectedBackgroundColor =
            ContextCompat.getColor(parent.getContext(), R.color.selected_background);
    mDefaultCardImage = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.movie, null);

    ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(parent.getContext()) {
        @Override
        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            updateCardBackgroundColor(this, selected);
            super.setSelected(selected);
        }
    }; 

    cardView.setAlpha(1.0f);
    cardView.setFocusable(false);
    cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    updateCardBackgroundColor(cardView, false);

    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create your presenter like so:

```
VerticalGridPresenter gridPresenter = new VerticalGridPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE,false);
```

the "false" is for enable / disable dimming

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start using these helper classes that are primarily used for applying dim level or color to your View.

- [ColorOverlayDimmer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/graphics/ColorOverlayDimmer.html)

  Helper class for assigning a dim color to Paint. It holds the alpha value for the current active level.
- [ColorFilterDimmer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/graphics/ColorFilterDimmer.html)

  Helper class for applying a dim level to a View. The ColorFilterDimmer uses a ColorFilter in a Paint object to dim the view according to the currently active level.

Sample implementation codes in Java can be found [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=platform_frameworks_support-master/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.java). Hope it helps!